# How to get internet connection iLO 4

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, hp

I'm using Ubuntu on my new HP PROLIANT DL320E GEN8. I have the server connected to my local network but it looks like Ubuntu don't have a connection to the net. When I checked all attached devices I found a device called iLO 4 connected with the same mac address as my server. It looks like this iLO service stops any incoming/outgoing connections.

Does anyone know how to give Ubuntu internet connection?

Thanks in advance, Carl

Comment: i am haveing the same issue now in the same device, how you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should have 2 connections from your server to the switch.  One for ILO and the other like Eth0  In your boot up Ilo config screen, you should see the ip address that it has been assigned.  ILO is totally separate from the software side of the server.  I am thinking that you need to install a ethernet cable to your eth0 connection and retry.
My Ilo uses port 443 passthrough BTW.